# How can I smooth a seam between cement board?

Tags: tile, self-leveling-concrete, cement-board

I have a joint between two sheets of cement board that forms a small ridge elevated maybe 1/8" relative to the centers of either board.  I was wondering if extra thinset on both sides can be used to even it out or is it better to use self-leveling compound beforehand.  I am using expensive marble tiles and don't want them to break to an unevenness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may break a few pieces(of marble) just picking them up.

A skim coat on either side of the joint will help.

Block feather with a concrete 'rubbing' block.

My marble floor always have Schluter Ditra under them.  I also use it with any questionable floor.

Ceramic tile can tolerate L/360 deflection, stone is twice as sensitive at L/720.

If you have any doubts about floor springiness, use an isolation membrane or stiffen joists or add a beam.  Cement board does little for stiffness.

Comment: a skim coat of what?

Comment: Thinset mortar.

Comment: what if i just dump some self-leveling on either side and wait for it to solidify before setting thinset?

Comment: as far as Schluter Ditra, do i set that using thinset and then again thinset on top between it and the tile?

Comment: You can use leveling mortar first.  Ditra is set based on the substrate, usually polymer modified thinset over ply or cement board.  For most marble, a white thinset is best.

Comment: Ditra vs. no Ditra -- how much thickness does it add to the substrate?

Comment: 1/8" + 1/16 for thinset